# Audio to MemoryStream in tethering

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to move an mp3 file using a MemoryStream as a parameter tetheringapppofile. The problem is that when loading this mp3 gives me an error of "Parameter out of range". Currently I try to do so:

```
TForm1.PlayerRemoto procedure (Sender: TObject);
var
   newDish: TMemoryStream;
   // sound: TSoundItem;
begin
   newDish: = TMemoryStream.Create;
   try
     newDish.LoadFromFile ('/ sdcard2 / music / EMANUELLE.mp3');
     newDish.Position: = 0;
     AppProfile.SendStream (Manager.RemoteProfiles.Items [0], 'Music', newDish); <- Parameter out of range
   finally
     newDish.Free
   end;
end;
```

Someone would know the best way to do this ??

Greetings and thank you very much.

Comment: It's probably complaining about this: Manager.RemoteProfiles.Items [0], suggesting Items is empty.

Comment: Why use a memory stream. That requires your device to load the entire file to memory and then send it. Use a file stream. You also appear to have posted made up code. Please post real code.